# What is a UTM code?

Tags: url, tags, preferences, identify

**What Are UTM Codes and How Do You Use Them?**

When you are navigating looking for products, there are some information about
you are looking for, that remains unvisible on the navigator and some pages uses them for identify your preferences.

*Why appears some "&utm" references on url?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are query string variables used by [Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863#parameters) to tag links with additional metadata.

The "UTM" part refers to the historical "Urchin Tracking Module", as Google bought the [Urchin company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urchin_(software)) and evolved it into the Analytics product.